# Определить количество обратных слешей

Tags: java

Как в пути (например, `d:\\WrkFld\\JJJ\\Адреса` или `d:\WrkFld\JJJ\Адреса`) определить количество обратных слешей (`\\` или `\`)?

Comment: При публикации вопроса, в нем двойной слеш "\\" в первом варианте пути заменен на одинарный "\"  !!!!

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ взят вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910767/690987)

```
int count = line.length() - line.replace("\\", "").length();
```

Comment: кхм, а что это нельзя сделать не создавай новой строки? Это же какие расходы не нужные

Comment: line.replace("\\", "") использовать нельзя - первая переменная "\\"  char, вторая  - String. replace(char, char).

Comment: @Леонид05-05 там оба параметра String.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    if (str.charAt(i) == '\\') count++;
```